# Java IO, are these resources automatically closed?

Tags: java, file-io, io, stream

In this code I read a text file, when BufferedReader  is closed by "try-resource" block so the InputStreamReader does, then can I guarantee all the resources are closed like this?

```
try(final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new 
    FileInputStream(file), charset))) {
        String line = null;

        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);

        }

    }
```

In this other example, I write a text file, as is written, are all the resources closed in the end? Is it mandatory to call flush()?

```
try(final BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new 
    FileOutputStream(file), charset))) {
        bw.write(text);
        bw.flush();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the outermost streams call their inner streams' `close()` methods, so you only need to call the outermost stream.

You don't need to call `flush()`, the streams will flush when necessary and before being closed. Remove that and the code will look perfect.